# How do I check if a path exists in Zookeeper using Curator?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm currently in the early stages of development to integrate Zookeeper stuff into my app. I'm using Netflix's Curator as an API for dealing with Zookeeper. I get the gist of most of it (like adding ZNodes and whatnot).

But how the heck do you check if a ZNode exists? The code that seems like it would work is:

```
client.checkExists().forPath(path);
```

...Where `client` is an instance of `com.netflix.curator.framework.CuratorFramework`

However, this call returns a `org.apache.zookeeper.data.Stat` object.

Using this object, how can I tell if a path exists or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `org.apache.zookeeper.data.Stat` object is metadata about that ZNode. (It's conceptually similar to how [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) tells you information about a file on the filesystem, hence the name.) `checkExists().forPath()` returns a `Stat` if it exists, or `null` if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured.